# Manually installing most recent compilers locally on gentoo

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gentoo

I like to play with recent versions of compilers and tools, for example I like to compile the weekly gcc snapshot and test new c++ features or test the most recent CMake.

I compile these and don't install them or install them somewhere inside my home directory (usually by using `--prefix`) but since I am using gentoo I don't want these snapshots to interfere when I compile something for my whole system.

Can I safely install these compilers and tools to `/usr/local` without them interfering with the packages I install with emerge?

Does it change anything if I run emerge from root or with sudo? (with `/usr/local` being in the `PATH` of the sudo user)

## EDIT

The output of $PATH

from root:
`/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

from a normal user using sudo
`/home/vicfred/.local/bin/:/usr/lib/llvm/9/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin`

Comment: Add the output of `echo $PATH` to your question, please.

Comment: Any compiler installed by portage will be managed by the system tools.  As a check: `gcc-config -l`.  Thats a small l, not a one.  If the compiler you installed in `/usr/local` is on the list, then you'll have issues. If not, you're OK